# Chrome reporting URL SAFE CHECK STATUS

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I was searching through internet about my issue from this morning but without result. Here is what I see in my chrome console:

> ContentDispatcherService: no listeners for an event
>   URLS_SAFE_CHECK__STATUS_UPDATED

Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In my case it was a Chrome extension called "Urban VPN". If it is installed on your machine, try to disable it and the message should go away. I hope it helps you

Comment: Yes, that caused the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly caused buy Urban VPN.
So its either, you disable urban VPN or you use another browser without a VPN on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes after disabling the VPN extension the message which is showing in the console goes away.

Answer (score -1):

I also have this problem because of "Urban VPN". You should just remove this extension from Google Chrome

Answer (score -2):

In my case, It was Urban VPN too. It wasn't enough disabled the plugin, but we need to remove it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).